# inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to export my Angular app as an npm module to be consumed by other applications, but am running into some difficulties. I have not been able to find this error anywhere else on the internet, and am at my wit's end.

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

I used ng-packagr to export my app as an npm module. I can successfully install it from a local folder on a barebones test app, but cannot get it to display my app.

Error:

```
    AppComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at inject (core.js:1362)
    at ChangeStackService_Factory (template-wiz.js:2074)
    at _callFactory (core.js:8223)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8181)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8156)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8849)
    at resolveDep (core.js:9214)
    at createClass (core.js:9094)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:8971)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10191)
```

template-wiz.module.ts (Module being exported)

```js
    import { NgModule, ChangeDetectorRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
    import { TemplateWizComponent } from './template-wiz.component';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BlockListDirective } from './Directives/block-list.directive';
    import { TemplateItemsDirective } from './Directives/template-items.directive';
    import { ContextMenuComponent, SeperatorComponent, DragBoxComponent, SnapLineComponent, PropertiesComponent, ToolboxComponent } from './Components'
    import { AddressBlockComponent, TextBlockComponent, ImageBlockComponent, DataBlockComponent } from './Data-Blocks';
    import { BlockFactoryService, BlockRegistryService, DisplayInfoService, MouseClickService, SavingService, SnapService, TextHelperService, UserModeService } from './Services';
    import { PageContextMenuComponent } from './Components/page-context-menu/page-context-menu.component';
    import { CamelToWordsPipe } from './Pipes/camel-to-words.pipe';
    import { PdfPublisherService } from './Services/pdf-publisher/pdf-publisher.service';
    import { GradientBlockComponent } from './Data-Blocks/gradient-block/gradient-block.component';
    import { PropToTypePipe } from './Pipes/prop-to-type.pipe';
    import { ShapeBlockComponent } from './Data-Blocks/shape-block/shape-block.component';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      entryComponents: [
        AddressBlockComponent,
        ContextMenuComponent,
        DragBoxComponent,
        GradientBlockComponent,
        ImageBlockComponent,
        PageContextMenuComponent,
        SeperatorComponent,
        ShapeBlockComponent,
        SnapLineComponent,
        TextBlockComponent
      ],
      declarations: [
        TemplateWizComponent,
        DataBlockComponent,
        AddressBlockComponent,
        SeperatorComponent,
        BlockListDirective,
        TemplateItemsDirective,
        ImageBlockComponent,
        TextBlockComponent, DragBoxComponent,
        SnapLineComponent,
        ToolboxComponent,
        PropertiesComponent,
        ContextMenuComponent,
        PageContextMenuComponent,
        GradientBlockComponent,
        CamelToWordsPipe,
        PropToTypePipe,
        ShapeBlockComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        BlockFactoryService,
        BlockRegistryService,
        DisplayInfoService,
        MouseClickService,
        SavingService,
        SnapService,
        TextHelperService,
        UserModeService,
        PdfPublisherService
      ],
      //bootstrap: [TemplateWizComponent],
      exports: [
        TemplateWizComponent
      ]
    })
    export class TemplateWizModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: TemplateWizModule,
          providers: [
            ComponentFactoryResolver
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

app.module.ts (Bare bones test app using my module)

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { TemplateWizModule } from 'template-wiz';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        TemplateWizModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Any help or pointers at all would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try updating your lib to Angular 6, this version include lib creation support. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library

Comment: Thank you for the tip, this project was written in angular 6. I was hoping to avoid having to turn the app into a library, but it may be unavoidable.

Comment: Have you checked your package versions? Seems from [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10586) others have reported the same error as you

Answer (score 193):

There seems to be an issue when using `npm link` when consuming the library.

Solution: use `projects.$name.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks: true` in the angular.json file of the client project, not the library.

Further information: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813

Comment: Great it worked for me. Additionally for me this issue comes only when we run `ng serve` without --prod flag.

Comment: I was looking for the solution for over one day. This works for me at the end! Thanks!

Comment: Life saving. I would never try `preserveSymlinks` for a "inject() must be called from an injection context" error. Just to make it clear: the change is to be made on the client project, not the lib project.

Comment: thank you very much! This should be marked as solution.

Comment: Also I bumped into this issue twice. In one case, preserveSymlinks helped. In the other case the problematic package was not symlinked, but installed classically via npm. The problem was that it was built with different version of Angular than the client app. One can easily check if it is the cause - in client app's node_modules, the folder with the library package contained another node_modules with its own version of Angular.

Comment: In my case I also needed to add `preserveSymlinks: true` in angular.json under `projects.$name.architect.test.options`.

Comment: The comment from @rslemos is very crucial! Thanks!

Comment: this was the solution that solved my problem. thanks so much!

Answer (score 32):

Here's what solved it for me :

Add the following line in `tsconfig.app.json` under `compilerOptions` :

```
"paths": { "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ] }
```

Source : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813#issuecomment-500091900

Comment: This definitely worked for me with Webpack v4.43.0 and Angular v8.2.14.

Comment: Worked with anguler 10

Comment: Not working for me in Angular 11 linking a generated client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709951/getting-inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-after-upgrading-to-a

Comment: I can confirm this solved the issue for me in Angular 12

Comment: I can confirm as well that this resolved my issue after updating from ng11 to ng12

Comment: This works but you need to edit the path to target your current node_modules directory relative to the tsconfig file

Comment: Thanks for the link @StefanFalk https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718393/217408 was what I had wrong.

Comment: Worked in Angular 13 for me. This never was a problem for Angular 11 and 12 though.

Comment: That did work for me, however with one dot instead of two (`./node_modules/...`), seen at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813#issuecomment-584866010

Comment: If it helps, i have library -> application setup.

I had to do this in both application and library. NOT JUST IN LIBRARY

Comment: Works in angular 15

Answer (score 26):

Same issue but my case was dumber...

I ran `npm install something` in the wrong folder.

So just remove the wrong "node_modules" and `npm install` in the correct folder x)

Comment: Ah Thank god man, I was facing this since yesterday, & this helped me

Comment: Man do I ever owe you a beer. Thanks!

Comment: All hail to the savior :) thank you man. I was having a problem with ngx-paypal throwing this error from inside. I would never find this without you. Actually, I had multiple projects in the wrong folder, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error.

I found that I was importing `Inject` from `@angular/core` instead of `@angular/core/testing`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I ended up switching it into a component library in Angular 6, and it ended up working much better. Would recommend the same to anyone else. Thank you for the insight however

Comment: I was unit testing and this answer solved my problem

Comment: Devil is in the details :)

Answer (score 10):

I my case it was because this code was missing in `test-setup.ts`.
I had only the first 2 lines.

```
import 'jest-extended';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
});
```

What made it a bit difficult was that I got a different unhelpul error even after adding this code because it was an Angular library package with its own `package.json` where the dependency `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` was missing.

Above helped, but I removed this code again.
What actually helped was https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718393/217408

A publishable package

- must not have `dependencies`, only `peerDependencies`
- `npm install` should not be run. The library must not contain a `node_modules` directory.

It was confusing that having `dependencies` and `node_modules` worked fine since months, but suddenly started failing and now even older commits don't work anymore without fixing above points.

Comment: This is what worked for me, remove the `node_modules` and explicit dependencies from the library project.

Answer (score 8):

I ran in a similar problem. Using a angular lib within an angular app with npm link.

As mentioned: "Solution: use projects.$name.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks: true in the angular.json file of the client project, not the library." works when serving the appliction with "ng serve".

However the error still was there when unit testing the application with "ng test". Adding preserveSymLinks in the the angular.json file here:

projects.$name.architect.test.options.preserveSymlinks: true

fixed that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this! I had a similar scenario with using a local `@ncstate/sat-popover` that I adapted for Angular 13 since their official repo doesn't yet support Angular13.

Answer (score 6):

### Update 2022

I was facing this problem in a Angular Library workspace. My directory structure looks like this

```
project
│   package.json
│
└───projects
│   │
│   └─── myLibApp
│       │   file111.txt
│       │   file112.txt
│       │   ...
│   
└─────── myLibExampleApp
```

I wanted to add some dependencies to my main library and I did `npm i` inside the `myLibApp` folder caused this problem. I had to remove the `node_modules` inside the lib & provide dependencies both in root level `package.json` as well as inside the `lib` but do `npm i` only in the root.

[Also ended up here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713195/8368871)

Comment: Life saving! God bless you!

Comment: thank you a lot @HariHaran , it was exactly this issue and no one in the internet specified this hint! you are a life saver <3 ,
I guess this answer should be voted with a lot of points ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here

My Case: When I was using Mat Dialog

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

 constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<MatConfirmDialogComponent>) { }
```

inject & Inject are different:

inject is a function and Inject is Interface

I hope this helps someone who comes finding the same scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone that runs into this problem and uses **Angular Universal** and a custom Angular Library linked with npm link:

The mentioned solution to add preserveSymlinks to your angular.json `projects.$name.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks: true`
is missing two parts.

For `dev:ssr` or `serve:ssr` to work, you need to add it aditionaly here:
`projects.$name.architect.server.options.preserveSymlinks: true`

And as mentioned in another comment, If you use tests, don't forget it here:
`projects.$name.architect.test.options.preserveSymlinks: true`

If there is yet another use case / location not listed here, comment it below.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error message `inject() must be called from an injection context` when I was creating a [tree-shakable `InjectionToken`](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#tree-shakable-injectiontoken) that used another `InjectionToken` in its factory, e.g.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { dependeeToken } from './dependee.token';

export const dependingToken = new InjectionToken<string>('depending', {
  factory: () => inject(dependeeToken) + ' depending';
  providedIn: 'root',
});
```

Instead, I added a provider for the depending `InjectionToken` to an `NgModule`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { dependeeToken } from './dependee.token';
import { dependingToken } from './depending.token';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      deps: [dependeeToken],
      provide: dependingToken,
      useFactory: dependee => dependee + ' depending',
    }
  ],
})
export class DependingModule {}
```

`package.json` excerpt

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.8.4",
    "@angular/cli": "6.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.9",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was to use the providedIn property in the Injectable decorator instead of registering the service in the app module in the providers for the service which was causing me this error message.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when building angular `9.0.0-next.0` with `ng build --prod` command. Downgrading to version `~8.2.8` made my angular app work again.

It was working well in development with `ng serve`, so it seems to be linked to Ivy.

Answer (score 0):

If the error appears on Karma with tests, just delete de *node_modules* folder and install again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem in testing an Angular application. The application imported a Service that had been installed from @bit with npm. The service depended on the MatSnackBar which seemed to be causing the same error as the OP.

To get the tests to run I instantiated the service when configuring the testing module.

In the example below, the `AsyncUIFeedbackService` was installed from Bit via npm. Setting the `useValue` to a new instance of the service, and stubbing the `MatSnackBar` worked great.

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [GeneralInfoComponent],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        { provide : AsyncUIFeedbackService, 
          useValue: new AsyncUIFeedbackService({} as MatSnackBar)}, // <----Create the service
      ],
      imports: [AsyncUIFeedbackModule]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was importing Inject from @angular/core instead of @angular/core/testing.

Answer (score 0):

Background: this is my own Angular 9 app as I was trying to locally import my own Angular 9 library

My issue was this flag in the `tsconfig.json` of my own library which I had built locally:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
```

According to the Angular documentation:

> When true, reports an error for a supplied parameter whose injection type cannot be determined. When false, constructor parameters of classes marked with @Injectable whose type cannot be resolved produce a warning. The recommended value is true, but the default value is false.

https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#strictinjectionparameters

To be honest, I don't know much about that flag beyond that description and can go without it; it was generated in a new project anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mean, I'm working with Angular2 and Firebase Real time Database (rtdb), I get the same error after getting some help from chatGPT, copying some code script and pasting it to my project.

I see a junky line like this `private database: Database = inject(Database);`
and never use it in the project.

After commenting this line, it works.
If you inject() something in Angular2, you have to use it.
That's it.