# Angular shows table breaks page

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Ive been using angular for a while took a year break to do some other stuff, then coming back to develop a new website i was developing a website which seemed to be working fine, until i tried importing the mat-table and all its dependencies.

here is my .ts code for the maincomponent i have

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

as soon as i remove the MatTableModule line in the imports part. the page shows back as usual again.

.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}
```

.html file

```
    <!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <img
    width="40"
    alt="game logo"
    src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/valorant_esports_gamepedia_en/thumb/d/d9/Logo_square.png/123px-Logo_square.png?version=4e7ad8c9f85ac6ace6fa98cf2eecdbeb"
  />
  <span>Valorant LFG</span>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!--anything for the right side of toolbar-->
</div>

<div class="content" role="main">
  <!-- Options -->
  <h2>Create a valorant team of your own, allowing other playerrs to join you</h2>

  <div class="card-container">

    <a class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">
      <img class="createteamicon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1189/1189206.png" alt="handshake" width="45" height="45">

      <span>Create Team</span>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Current LFG Requests, resets after 24 hours</h2>
  </div>

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

im sure ive done something very small but this is my small issue atm.

this is the console error on chrome

https://gyazo.com/05a62301b4937a8669690f1c2168f32b

if you have any answers to this it would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you check console for errors?

Comment: it comes through all fine on the console saying compiled succesfully like usual

Comment: Did you happen to run
 ```$ cd your_angular_project$ ng add @angular/material ```

before Importing the Angular Material Data-Table Module?

Comment: Where is your page's component.ts and html parts? This is just app.module. Please share AppComponent.html and ts codes too

Comment: @IsaacLyne, can you please confirm which version of angular app you have and which version of @angular/material package you have installed ?

Comment: @pc_coder ill edit it now to add those in

Comment: @IsaacLyne https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k83ww6 it seems to be working

Comment: @luckyy it must be in the other code then for it to still not be working for me

Comment: https://gyazo.com/05a62301b4937a8669690f1c2168f32b this is the console error on chrome

Comment: @IsaacLyne that time you said there were no errors, can you please edit the editor link I have sent you. Just add html and ts code to reproduce it. Without viewing the error code it is difficult to find out.

Comment: I used your given HTML file as well. It is still working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following tutorial for a detailed explanation of how to use the Material Data-Table Module.

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-material-table/

Comment: dont think i did ng add before hand

Answer (score 0):

add angular material to ur project

```
ng add @angular/material 
npm i 
ng serve
```

Comment: just did and it didnt seem to change anything, still white screen

Comment: can u share ur console screen in ur browser

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6715d66af41bac6104fc540322973a42                                              https://gyazo.com/81b06562275ed3c2a368545dbe14f5e3

Comment: https://gyazo.com/05a62301b4937a8669690f1c2168f32b console error on chrome

Comment: check the issues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485868/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context

Answer (score 0):

I still dont know what i did, but i made a new project and installed the materials and imported tables again and it worked this time so i just copied the files over to that one and it works