# Getting "inject() must be called from an injection context" after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc

After upgrading to Angular 11, I am not able to `ng serve` my web application anymore.

I am generating the client using Spring Doc and the latest OpenAPI generator gradle-plutin (5.0.0).

The problem appears to be related to my (generated) REST-client. Opening https://localhost:4200 will write the following into the console:

```
main.ts:12 Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4901) [angular]
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4911) [angular]
    at Object.ApiModule_Factory [as factory] (meditation-rest-client.js:2885) [angular]
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11158) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:10979) [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:82591:55 [angular]
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>) [angular]
    at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11016) [angular]
    at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25046) [angular]
    at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25100) [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:100468:45 [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28301) [angular]
```

The following is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I define the dependency in `package.json`

```json
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.2",
    "meditation-rest-client": "./generated/meditation-rest-client",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
```

And this here are those generated lines which are reffered to in the error message above:

```js
// ...

ApiModule.ɵmod = ɵngcc0.ɵɵdefineNgModule({ type: ApiModule });
ApiModule.ɵinj = ɵngcc0.ɵɵdefineInjector({ factory: function ApiModule_Factory(t) { return new (t || ApiModule)(ɵngcc0.ɵɵinject(ApiModule, 12), ɵngcc0.ɵɵinject(ɵngcc1.HttpClient, 8)); }, providers: [], imports: [[]] });
ApiModule.ctorParameters = () => [
    { type: ApiModule, decorators: [{ type: Optional }, { type: SkipSelf }] },
    { type: HttpClient, decorators: [{ type: Optional }] }
];

// ...
```

This used to work in Angular 9 but it won't under Angular 11.

Any idea how to fix this? I already tried setting `"preserveSymlinks": true` as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813) and [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5246).

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue could arise due to the generated npm package builds into some output folder `/generated/meditation-rest-client`.
When being referenced by the frontend application, the api package resolves the import `@angular/core` to `/generated/meditation-rest-client/node_modules/@angular/core`, differing from the `/node_modules/@angular/core` in the project root.

The resolution would be to delete the `/generated/meditation-rest-client/node_modules` folder and the `node_modules` folder in the parents, except for the `<project-root>/node_modules`. Alternatively, the generated code `/generated/meditation-rest-client` should be copied to some location where no parent folder contains an `node_modules` folder.

See https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8447

Comment: This was precisely my case. Other team's package had `@angular/core` and other angular packages set as production dependencies instead of devDependencies which should be used only for building their library. Will have to connect with them and get this fixed. Thanks a lot, sir.

Answer (score 17):

If this is a multi project setup (aka monorepo), you have to take care of the following:

- The root (the folder which has the `projects` subdir) should have a `package.json` and a `node_modules` directory
- Only projects of type `library` have a `package.json` and they should have only peer dependencies. **DON'T** run `npm install` here! There MUST NOT be a `node_modules` directory here
- application projects don't have a `package.json` at all and as such don't have a `node_modules` either
- The library doesn't need to be listed as a dependency. Use paths in `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` to use it.

I found this example skeleton project at github helpful to fix my injection problem:

https://github.com/PeterKassenaar/ng-monorepo

Comment: I had this problem, and with your advice, I resolved it.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issues too, I'm working on a monorepo with publishable UI-packages. Upgraded from Angular 9 to 13.

Comment: Thank you, must of had `cd` into the library by accident and did npm install. Spent whole day figuring out what's wrong and was about to delete my library and redo.

Comment: Thank you! my problem was that I had `node_modules` directory in library. As you stated, `node_modules` should only be in the root directory of project