# Error: inject() must be called from an injection context when deploying with Angular 9 or Angular 10

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular9, angular-universal, angular10

I am upgrading Angular on my project and I have faced this issue. Currently I am able to start my project locally successfully, however when I try to deploy it and start it through the server I get an internal server error. The build completes and launches my project on port but when I open it through a browser the following error is thrown:

```
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
at injectInjectorOnly (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:198150:15)
at ɵɵinject (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:198160:57)
at Object.ApplicationModule_Factory [as factory] (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:226795:130)
at R3Injector.hydrate (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:677770:35)
at R3Injector.get (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:677591:33)
at /Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:677628:55
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:677628:31)
at new NgModuleRef$1 (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:690724:26)
at NgModuleFactory$1.create (/Users/vasko/Downloads/PROJECT/client/dist/server.js:690778:16)
```

It seems to be some server side rendering issue. I have spent a lot of time trying to resolve this but I have not come to any usefull fix.

I have tried:

1. Adding `"preserveSymlinks": true` in my `angular.json` file undeer `projects.project-name.architect.build.options`. The same error occurs again.
2. Adding `"@angular/*": ["../../node_modules/@angular/*"]` and `"@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]` in under `compilerOptions.paths` in my `tsconfig.app.json`. The same error occurs again.
3. Adding `"enableIvy": false` under `"angularCompilerOptions"` in `tscofing.app.json`. A bunch of HTML errors occurred but the same internal error occurred once I solved the HTML ones.
4. Upgrading to Angular 10, the same error occurs.
5. Commenting out all of the services in `app.module.ts`. The same error occurs.
6. Tried adding @Injectable above each component which has @Inject in its constructor. Read about this from [here](https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility-examples#undecorated-classes), but as expected the same error occurred. Angular components are injectable by default.

Most of these solutions came from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485868/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context) and this [Github Issues Request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813#issuecomment-500091900)

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error? I can immediately edit the question and post my files if they are required.

Comment: When you upgrade you are bound to encounter various issues with typescript. Your best bet is to solve one item at a time until all the errors are resolved. Also why would you deploy an app that is not even building locally?

Comment: I may have worded my question poorly. It's working when I start it locally using ng serve, but it fails when I try to deploy it on a server and start it from there.

Comment: Are you able to run `ng build --aot --prod` successfully?

Comment: I made some changes to angular.json and managed to build it without those warnings.

Comment: @VaskoVasilev could you share the changes you made? I upgraded a project from angular 11 to angular 12 and am running into the same problem.