# Angular module federation with multiple angular versions of angular core for shell and micro-frontends

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I'm using angular module-federation library. I'm using a shell application that uses angular 13.1.1 version. There are few micro frontends that uses angular 13.1.1 version. There is one micro frontend that uses angular 14.2.6. The micro frontends that uses angular 13.1.1 work fine. However, I'm getting the following error, when the micro frontend application that uses angular 14.2.6 is accessed.

Subscriber.js:91 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.

I have the following configuration in the shell application's webpack.config.js

`shared: share({ "@angular/core": { requiredVersion: 'auto' }, "@angular/common": { requiredVersion: 'auto' }, "@angular/common/http": { requiredVersion: 'auto' }, "@angular/router": { requiredVersion: 'auto' }, "@angular/animations": { requiredVersion: 'auto' }, ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()})`

This has been suggested in the following website as well https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/pitfalls-with-module-federation-and-angular/

I think the error is due to multiple angular versions. But, I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: It sounds like it could be a "linkage error" (for lack of a better term): your runtime (however you built it) is picking up the wrong module from the wrong place.  Look at some of the different posts in this thread for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647323/421195.  See also [How do I fix "Inject() must be called from an injection context"?](https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2022/1/4/How-do-I-fix-Inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the solution and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? Did you find the solution?