# Angular 9 - The target entry-point has missing dependencies

Tags: angular, angular9

I have upgraded an Angular library to Angular 9.   However when I attempt to use that library in another Angular 9 project I get an error like this:

The target entry-point "mycomponents/entity-selector" has missing dependencies:

```
 - mycomponents/shared-services
 - mycomponents/spinner
 - mycomponents/text-input
```

Package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "name": "entity-selector",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
    },
    "dest": "../../../dist/mycomponents/entity-selector"
  }
}
```

This is a secondary endpoint which uses other components which are also secondary endpoints.

In the library project do I need to some define the dependencies in ng-packgr or somewhere else?  The module for the entity-selector component imports the appropriate module for the other components.  This issue cropped up since Angular 9.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant sections of your library's package.json?

Comment: @ScottWalter Did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: any answer yet?

Comment: No solution yet.  However this hasn't been a focus lately but I do need to get back to it.

Answer (score 30):

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "primeng" has missing dependencies: - chart.js

ERROR in The target entry-point "primeng" has missing dependencies: - quill

ERROR in The target entry-point "primeng" has missing dependencies: - @fullcalendar/core


npm install --save chart.js
npm install --save quill
npm install --save @fullcalendar/core
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. Try adding more info about pasted code.

Comment: How would upgrading angular version make dependencies get lost?

Answer (score 19):

## The First Problem

You're getting that error because your test project does not have those dependencies installed in its `node_modules/` directory.  But I believe that doing as @Renato suggests and forcing the users of your library to manually install those dependencies is the wrong approach.

In order to have the missing dependencies automatically installed, it's [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51909168/2517147) to add your library's 3rd party dependencies in two places (within the library itself):

- `package.json` at the root of the library.  I believe you already have this done.
  Putting all packages here ensures that there is only a single `node_modules/` directory at the root when you run your project for development.
- `projects/entity-selector/package.json` is the file that is used as the basis for the package.json file that Angular generates when you build your library.  It is necessary to add the dependencies here so that the consumers of your library know which packages they (well, their package manager) need to download.  I believe that this is what you're currently missing.

## The Second Problem

After properly adding my dependencies to both places, I got build errors telling me that I should use "peerDependencies" and not "dependencies" for my library.

That is not applicable to my use case, so to get around it I had to explicitly whitelist my dependencies.  Doing so [looks a little different](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/716#issuecomment-378014856) depending on which of the following you're using:

- `projects/entity-selector/package.json`
- `projects/entity-selector/ng-package.json`.

In `projects/entity-selector/package.json` it should be:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
    },
    "dest": "../../../dist/mycomponents/entity-selector",
    "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
      "mycomponents/shared-services",
      "mycomponents/spinner",
      "mycomponents/text-input"
    ]
  }
}
```

In `projects/entity-selector/ng-package.json` it should be:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "mycomponents/shared-services",
    "mycomponents/spinner",
    "mycomponents/text-input"
  ]
}
```

---

Finally, don't forget to build your project with `ng build --prod` or you'll get an [error](https://angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility) about the new Ivy compiler when you try to publish to NPM!

Comment: Ahh let me give this a try later today.   We have an Angular workspace project where we have a component library and a sample app.   I was targeting the components (secondary endpoints) into the dist directory.    As well as we only have a package.json for each second endpoint and not a ng-package.json

Comment: This is the answer that really helped me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Modify your component project to change the absolute path to a relative path.

Such as:

```
import {xxx} from 'src/xxx/xxx.module';
```

to:

```
import {xxx} from '../../xxx/xxx.module';
```

Comment: I solve my problem with this modification. Thanks!

Comment: @yang zhou why would it solve the issue? What's the difference?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. This came after adding a symlink, so I had to use

```
npm unlink *@your/package*
```

or just globally

```
npm unlink
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasted almost half day and then realized this was the issue @AverageProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

I think I have just worked through the situation you describe. I have an NPM package called `my-pkg` that contains several "libraries" (created with `ng g library lib[1..N]`, etc). It just so happens that my `libN` depends on `lib1`. When I try to use `libN` in an application, I get the error:

```
The target entry-point "my-pkg/libN" has missing dependencies:
 - lib1
```

Here is how I originally imported `lib1` into `libN`:

```
// libN.component.ts
import { Lib1Comp } from 'lib1';
```

This works when I build `my-pkg`. The problem is that 'lib1' doesn't resolve to a top-level package inside my application's `node_modules` folder. There, it should be known as `my-pkg/lib1`. So, let's change the import in `libN.component.ts`:

```
// libN.component.ts
import { Lib1Comp } from 'my-pkg/lib1'; // note lib1 is now prefixed with my-pkg
```

Of course, we don't have `my-pkg` installed in `my-pkg`'s node_modules, so it can't find `my-pkg/lib1` and now `my-pkg` doesn't build.

But what if we were able to "install" `my-pkg` into it's own node_modules folder? Let's try copying it in there via NPM scripts:

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
    "copy:lib1": "npx copy .\\dist\\lib1\\**\\* .\\node_modules\\my-pkg\\lib1",
    "build:lib1": "ng build --prod lib1 && npm run copy:lib1",
    // repeat copy/build scripts as needed for libs[2..N]
    "build:pkg": "npm run build:lib1 && npm run build:libN"
},
```

Now, we run `npm run build:pkg`. It builds `lib1` then copies it to our local `node_modules` folder, and now `libN` can happily import from the path `my-pkg/lib1` in both your library and your application!

Answer (score 2):

`ngx-quill` needs library `quill` to be already installed
so just adding this solved the issue for me

`npm i quill@^1.3.7`

Answer (score 1):

In the project that imports your library, add the following to the `tsconfig.json`. This ensures that `tsc` is able to resolve the "missing dependencies" between submodules in your library.

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "mycomponents/*": [
        "./node_modules/mycomponents/*"
      ],
```

With this, there was no need for `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I had `The target entry-point has missing dependencies` error when starting my Angular project with `npm run start`. A simple solution that worked for me was to clone my project from GIT into a new folder on my local machine and then run `npm install`, `npm run start` on a clean project. The issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular and Primeng 9

> ERROR in The target entry-point "primeng" has missing dependencies:
>
> - chart.js

My import before:

```
import {ToastModule} from "primeng";
```

Solution:

```
import {ToastModule} from "primeng/toast";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```bash
npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-angular@latest
```

It worked for me.

Comment: please explain in more detail why dependecy is needed and how it solves the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).