# google-chart-angular is missing dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-google-chart

I'm setting up google-chart-angular in my angular project. I've installed it [according to this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-google-charts-in-angular/), and also added GoogleChartsModule to my app.module.ts

I think everything should just work fine, but when I start the project, it tells me the following:

```
Error: The target entry-point "angular-google-charts" has missing dependencies:
 - rxjs
 - @angular/core
 - rxjs/operators
```

How do I get rid of this? I've already tried the following:
just a overall npm install, didn't do anything.
I've also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60904384/14939166) from a different thread, but that didn't do anything as well and I got the same error messages.

Would be glad if somebody could help me right here, really struggling right now.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to do with the version. There maybe a possibility that the version on @angular/core required by angular-google-charts is bigger than the version installed in your system. Check the version of the dependencies required and the version available in the system. Either you will need to update the dependencies or degrade the angular-google-charts.