# The target entry-point "ngx-datetime-range-picker" has missing dependencies:

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular-material, unhandled-exception, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I am trying to use the ngx-datetime-range-picker package in my application.

it is installed in my application. But it shows error while using it in Module as  below :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "ngx-datetime-range-picker" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/material/button
 - @angular/material/form-field
 - @angular/material/icon
 - @angular/material/input
 - @angular/material/select

See "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-4MVzaD\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I don't know how to import all these missing dependencies to my application. Please help me.

Comment: try this solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214324/angular-9-the-target-entry-point-has-missing-dependencies

Comment: what version of angular do you have?